# I can't access EnforceConstraints?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am not even sure if I am going to ask this question properly, so bear with me as my knowledge of C# has been all on the job for the past 2 years so I am sure I am missing some rudimentary programming knowledge.

I recently took over a project and the previous programmer had some interesting "styles" including using compiled DLLs and the like. The problem I am running into now is this:

It seems he "overwrote" the DataSet class as the current code looks like

```
TAU_DataSet.tblNodesDataTable dtNodes = new TAU_DataSet.tblNodesDataTable();            
TAU_DataSetTableAdapters.tblNodesTableAdapter daNodes = new     TAU_DataSetTableAdapters.tblNodesTableAdapter();
```

I can't even create a normal DataSet if I wanted to. At the moment the page is generating a "Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints." error. I know the query and everything else is ok because the same code and XSD is used on a mobile version of the site.

I thought I could just set EnforceConstraints to false to get around this error, but that returns the error that it doesn't contain definition for it.

I hope this isn't too vague. I am just trying to figure out how to get around this problem. Ideally the site would be re-written without compiled DLLs and the like but the site is big and it's up to people higher up than me to make that decision.

Comment: The compiled .dlls should represent separation of concerns and layers. As long as you have access to the source for those .dlls, you should be okay. If the previous programmer didn't leave source for those, you could be in for a re-write sprint.

Comment: Luckily the compiled DLLs aren't being used in this instance, though they have caused plenty of other headaches.

Answer (score 2):

You can always create a normal DataSet if you want:

```
global::System.Data.DataSet x = new global::System.Data.DataSet(); // example
```

It sounds like you're encountering some namespace collision issues or something?

Comment: So in Class View I found the where the custom TAU_DataSet is inheriting the Global.System.Data.DataSet.

How would I edit this inheritance so that the TAU_DataSet would include the EnforceContraints property?

Comment: Probably the constructor of the new type. If it's an inheritance, then the derived class should have the same property set as the parent.